# Upload large file with Multi Part Form Data using RestSharp

Tags: restsharp

I am developing a small application to upload large file using an Rest API.  The Rest API accepts multi part form data.  The upload should happen in stream.  I am using RestSharp to invoke this API.  I could upload small files, but when tried to upload 1GB file, it is taking longer time and i could not see any file in the destination.  I am not sure, if i am using streaming or loading complete data into memory.

Please find my code below.  Please share a C# sample code to upload large file stream using multi part form data.  Is there anything i am missing in the below code:

```
var client = new RestClient("https://xxxxxxxxxxxxx/UploadFile");
RestRequest request = new RestRequest("/", Method.POST);
request.AddHeader("FileName", txtFileName.Text.Trim().ToString());
request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
request.AddFile("fileData", txtFilePath.Text.Trim().ToString(), );
request.ReadWriteTimeout = 2147483647;
request.Timeout = 2147483647;
var response = client.Execute(request);
```

Thanks,
Rajkumar